# Is it possible to have an array of smart pointers that automatically updates its values with their index?

Tags: c++, arrays, smart-pointers

In C++, is there a way to write an array of smart pointers that automatically updates the pointed-to values with their index in the array? The pointed-to values have a member to store the index, similar to an intrusive refcount.

I am interested in writing a heap with updatable priorities. If the values in the heap were always updated to point to their index inside the heap storage, without special knowledge inside the heap algorithm, it would be easy to follow that link back into the heap when changing the value's priority. Knowing the position of the changed item, the heap invariant could then be quickly restored.

Comment: I think you'd need to encapsulate the heap (i.e. the array) in a container-like type which does that updating for you every time it modifies the heap.

Comment: Of course it's possible. You just need to write the smart pointer for it. Should be a relatively straight-forward task.

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt at a basic implementation. I would prefer to parameterize `Container`s reference to the global array without making instances larger than one pointer, and it would be good to improve safety. It would be more useful if it was also a random access iterator.

```
class Contained {
    public:
        uintptr_t index;
};

class Container {
    public:
        Contained *value;

    Container& operator=(Container& other);
};

Container foobars[4];

Container& Container::operator=(Container& other) {
    this->value = other.value;
    this->value->index = ((uintptr_t)this - (uintptr_t)foobars) / sizeof(this->value);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Also, this doesn't appear to be valid C++11